Где скачать документацию к jdk-23
Где скачать архив документации к jdk-23?
Проблема в том, что idea не отображает полную документацию в quick documentation, а конкретно не выводит список методов.
Что лично я попробовала:

удалить jdk, скачать новый(не помогло)
проверить папки внутри скачанного с оф сайта jdk-23(нет папки doc)
проверила оф сайт, файла в формате архив нет, есть только страница на сайте
поискать в гугл(скачала с какого то сайта, итог - документация в идее просто обновила форматирование текста, список методов так и не появился, перестала работать кнопка «перейти на оф сайт»).

Чат гпт утверждает, что моя версия документации не полная и необходимо скачать полный файл.
Кто знает, где его взять?
